# No module named cv2 when importing camelot into python and

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, miniconda, python-camelot

Trying to import camelot on Macbook Pro OS 10.13.6 after successfully installing python and miniconda and importing pandas.  Everything else seemed to install and work but after import received error when importing camelot:

```
import camelot
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/camelot/init.py", line 6, in
from .io import read_pdf
File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/camelot/io.py", line 5, in
from .handlers import PDFHandler
File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/camelot/handlers.py", line 9, in
from .parsers import Stream, Lattice
File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/camelot/parsers/init.py", line 4, in
from .lattice import Lattice
File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/camelot/parsers/lattice.py", line 26, in
from ..image_processing import (
File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/camelot/image_processing.py", line 3, in
import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
import platform; print(platform.platform())
Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
import sys; print('Python', sys.version)
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan 8 2020, 13:42:34)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
import numpy; print('NumPy', numpy.version)
NumPy 1.18.4
import cv2; print('OpenCV', cv2.version)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
import camelot; print('Camelot', camelot.version)
```

The one parameter I see that I am wondering about is the Darwin parameter because I see in Anaconda.sh installer, it checks for configuration, and won't install if its equal to 'Darwin' configuration but the miniconda did not have that check. Does miniconda have the same limitation?  Is there a workaround that I need so it could even work with Jupiter notebook?  Currently, the exact same cv2 error occurs on Jupiter notebook that occurs on the laptop when I import camelot into the Jupiter notebook.  I thought these python tools existed there on the Jupiter notebook platform so I didn't need them all locally.

Comment: Can you share the packages installed in the Conda environment?

Comment: Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh was the pkg I used if that helps.  The Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg wouldnt install.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install opencv-python`
after downloading opencv module, I no longer have the error
[reference](https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/issues/286)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).